# Mocking Auth0Client in @auth0 in jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, auth0

I'm trying to mock out the `import { Auth0Provider } from "@auth0/auth0-react";` in a react app and keep running into issues with this error `[Error: For security reasons, window.crypto is required to run auth0-spa-js.]` From what I can tell this error is coming from the `Auth0Client` which gets imported from `import { Auth0Client } from '@auth0/auth0-spa-js';` My thought is to mock out the scoped module `@auth0/auth0-spa-js` and do something like this

```
const handleRedirectCallback = jest.fn(() => ({ appState: {} }));
const buildLogoutUrl = jest.fn();
const buildAuthorizeUrl = jest.fn();
const checkSession = jest.fn();
const getTokenSilently = jest.fn();
const getTokenWithPopup = jest.fn();
const getUser = jest.fn();
const getIdTokenClaims = jest.fn();
const isAuthenticated = jest.fn(() => false);
const loginWithPopup = jest.fn();
const loginWithRedirect = jest.fn();
const logout = jest.fn();

export const Auth0Client = jest.fn(() => {
  return {
    buildAuthorizeUrl,
    buildLogoutUrl,
    checkSession,
    handleRedirectCallback,
    getTokenSilently,
    getTokenWithPopup,
    getUser,
    getIdTokenClaims,
    isAuthenticated,
    loginWithPopup,
    loginWithRedirect,
    logout,
  };
});
```

This seems to be working if I import the `Auth0Client` into any of my tests, but the problem is that the `Auth0Provider` is still importing the non mocked out client. Is there anyway to get the `Auth0Provider` to import the mocked out `Auth0Client` instead of the actual implementation? The file that uses the `Auth0Provider` looks like this

```
// test-utils.js
import React from 'react'
import { render as rtlRender } from '@testing-library/react'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing';
import { Auth0Provider } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import { Auth0Client } from '@auth0/auth0-spa-js';

// Import your own reducer
import applicationsReducer from "../app/slices/applications.slice";
import { UserProvider } from "../user-context";

import {getUserMock} from "../__tests__/apollo_mocks/get_user.mock"

// const MockedAuth0Provider = jest.requireActual("@auth0/auth0-react").Auth0Provider

function render(
  ui,
  {
    initialState,
    mocks,
    store = createStore(applicationsReducer, initialState),
    ...renderOptions
  } = {}
) {
  function Wrapper({ children }) {
    return <Auth0Provider clientId="__test_client_id__" domain="__test_domain__">
              <Provider store={store}>
                <MockedProvider mocks={[getUserMock, ...mocks]} addTypename={false}>
                  <UserProvider>{children}</UserProvider>
                </MockedProvider>
              </Provider>
            </Auth0Provider>
  }
  return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions })
}

// re-export everything
export * from '@testing-library/react'
// override render method
export { render }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hopefully this helps someone else but I ended up mocking the provider as well as some of the other auth0 modules that I was using this way

```
jest.mock('@auth0/auth0-react', () => ({
  Auth0Provider: ({ children }) => children,
  withAuthenticationRequired: ((component, _) => component),
  useAuth0: () => {
    return {
      isLoading: false,
      user: { sub: "foobar" },
      isAuthenticated: true,
      loginWithRedirect: jest.fn()
    }
  }
}));
```

This is all in my `setupTests.js` file

Comment: I was struggling with this too. Can't understand why I'm mocking Auth0 globally but jest doesn't wanna pick that up. I'm using your setup and it is working like a charm!!! thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you!! 
I also added one more field returned from `useAuth0`: 
```
getAccessTokenSilently: jest
        .fn()
        .mockImplementation(
          () => new Promise(resolve => resolve("test-token"))
        ),
```